# jquery if statement to check if there is a value of an input otherwise auto populate upon clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple `jQuery` statement like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ltc_link').click(function() {
        $('#USERDEFINE1').val( 'LT' );
        $('#PHONENIGHT').val( '(111)111-1111' );
        $('#INTERNET').val( 'NONE' );
        $('#last_purchase').val( 'N/A' );
        $('#last_purchase_date').val( 'N/A' );
    });
});
```

It populates the input fields when the link `#ltc_link` is clicked.

If there is already text input into one or all of the fields than i don't want the click/link function to overwrite what the user entered. I know in javascript I can do something like so:

```
if (!third.value) { third.value = '(111)111-1111'; }
if (!fourth.value) { fourth.value = 'NONE'; }
if (!fifth.value) { fifth.value = 'N/A'; }
if (!sixth.value) { sixth.value = 'N/A'; }
```

Need some  help with the `jQuery` syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you're already using jQuery, you might want to consider using Knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/) which lets you create a "viewmodel", which you can then bind to your HTML controls. Knockout handles syncing the variables with the controls and vice-versa.

Comment: I'll have a look into knockoutjs, thank you.

Comment: And what's your HTML? If we know what you're working with we can (often) offer better answers.

Comment: It's just a few input boxes, thanks for answering, i'll test.

Comment: You're welcome, it works in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XdCYt/), so should work for you, unless you've something else going on to break it, or cause (unanticipated) problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var defaults = {
    USERDEFINE1 : 'LT',
    PHONENIGHT : '(111)111-1111',
    INTERNET : 'NONE',
    last_purchase : 'N/A',
    last_purchase_date : 'N/A'
};
$('#ltc_link').click(function() {
    // selects the elements
    $('#USERDEFINE1, #PHONENIGHT, #INTERNET, #last_purchase, #last_purchase_date').val(
        function(i, v) {
            // checks if the current value 'v' is an empty string,
            // if it is supplies the default value (from the object), if not
            // it sets the value to the current value
            return v == '' ? defaults[this.id] : v;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XdCYt/).

References:

- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: @ron: I'm glad to have *shown* you something new! May I ask what part(s) you didn't know about?

Comment: I did not realize that you could apply a function within the val() with an index into the selected elements.